# Can't get data on controller action .NET Core + Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

**My Angular 2 service:**

```
private verifyUserEmailUrl = 'api/admin/verifyuseremail';
verifyUserEmail(email: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('email', email);
    return this.http
        .get(this.verifyUserEmailUrl, { search: params })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return this.extractData(response);
        });
    }
```

**My controller action:**

```
[Route("[action]")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyUserEmail(string email)
{
    return Json(new Json("success", false));
}
```

I setup breakpoint in Visual Studio, but app doesn't go to that breakpoint. I've also tried to add `[FromQuery]` to `email`, but it didn't help. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#parse-to-json)

> The http.get does not send the request just yet. This Observable is
>   cold, which means that the request won't go out until something
>   `subscribes` to the Observable.

So you need to `subscribe` to your `Observable`. At the end you need to call `subscribe` function on it actually to do the request.

```
private verifyUserEmailUrl = 'api/admin/verifyuseremail';

verifyUserEmail(email: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('email', email);
    return this.http
        .get(this.verifyUserEmailUrl, { search: params })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return this.extractData(response);
        })
        .subscribe((data) => /* Your code here */);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller mapped wrong url. Use the mapping below.

```
[Route("api/admin/verifyuseremail")]
```